# Android App using opencv: how to save an image without overwriting?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm using the following code to save an image to a folder when I select an option:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
String filename = "teste.png";
File file = new File(path, filename);
filename = file.toString();
Highgui.imwrite(filename, mRgba);
```

But i'd like the saved image to NOT OVERWRITE the image that's already in the folder. How could I do that? Using a kind of index for each image or something like that, I think, but how?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try naming the file after the date. So String filename =new Date().toString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyAppDir");

if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
    if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to create directory");
        return null;
    }
}

String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
File mediaFile;
mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "testimage_" + timeStamp + ".png");
```