# unable to load haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml in OpenCV in Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, haar-classifier

I have following code block to load `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml` and check it. And I'm sure that haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml file path is true. Do you have any idea about this issue?

```
public static void FaceDetector (Mat image){

    String cascade_name="/home/ismailkaratepe/AndroidStudioProjects/FaceDetectionApp/app/src/main/res/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
    CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(cascade_name);
    faceDetector.load(cascade_name);

    if (faceDetector.empty()) {
        System.out.println("Face cascade failed to load.");
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Face cascade loaded successfully.");
    }
    ...
}
```

This always prints `Face cascade failed to load.`  What's wrong?

Comment: Maybe your application does not have the rights to read from your home folder?

Comment: I can not understand you clearly. But I'm sure that haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml path is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487770/permission-of-app-specific-folder-on-external-storage):

> You can not access an application's home directory, on an unrooted device. This would have been a MAJOR security hole.

You need to have a look about [where to store files](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) on android and then read your xml file from there

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681808/android-app-using-opencv-how-to-save-an-image-without-overwriting) there is an example which shows you how to read a file from your local app folder.

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyAppDir");
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) My problem is solved with your solution. I copied my .xml file to phone storage. Then in code I gave xml in phone storage path, application runs fine .

Comment: @İsmailKaratepe i am facing the same problem as you had. Please guide me